# I need to add " right click popup " option in the Jtree

Tags: java, swing, popup, popupwindow

I need to bring the popup menu when I right click on the selected value in the JTree.

Comment: Please show us that you have made something we can't help you with what your asking: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask  and Sun has made some magnificient tutorial about that : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29)

You may also find [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) of interest

Comment: @alex2410 Fastest (and fattest) fingers on an iPad ;)